# Highcharts- Tooltip HTML max width

Tags: highcharts

I am having some trouble getting the Tooltip for a series to not exceed a fixed width.  I would like to tooltip for the Notes to not exceed a certain width, but I don't want it to be a fixed width.

Here is a jsfiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/mnucci/hsBSV/

If you mouse over the second note at the top, it will be way too wide.

I am also having a problem getting the tooltip to honor the useHTML flag or the Formatter function.

I also tried using a style setting like

```
.highcharts-tooltip span {
    width:140px;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:normal !important;
}
```

but this fixed the width to 140 even when there were only 10 chars and I don't want all tooltips to inherit this, only the note series.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set `useHTML` as true

http://jsfiddle.net/hsBSV/1/

Comment: Thanks but why do I need to set useHTML: true in the SetOptions when I already had it for the series tooltip?  I just wanted it HTML to be used on this one series, not on all the series and that is why I set it for just this one series.  I would like the other series to have the default tooltip look.   I would also like the tooltip width for the note series to be a Max-Width not fixed to 140px so short notes don't have a lot of white space to the right.  Any suggestions?